# Assign a 2-dim real array in Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

I would like to assign a two-dimensional real array in Verilog.

The C-like [approach](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/mKRg) below does not work.

```
`timescale 1ns/10ps

module twodim ();
  
real xy[0:2][0:1] = {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}};
  
initial begin
  int n = 1;
  $display ("x[n] = %f y[n] = %f", xy[n][0], xy[n][1]);
  #1  $finish;
end
  
endmodule
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

EDAplayground is SystemVerilog, and the syntax you need to use is an assignment pattern. `'{}`. This is because Verilog already uses `{}` for integral concatenation. You can only use `{}` for a  single dimension of an array.

```
module twodim ();
  
real xy[0:2][0:1] = '{'{1, 1}, '{2, 4}, '{3, 9}};
  
initial begin
  int n; // static variable 
  n = 1;
  $display ("x[n] = %f y[n] = %f", xy[n][0], xy[n][1]);
  #1  $finish;
end
  
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for the SystemVerilog, solution. is something similar possible in simple Verilog?

Comment: No. Although you can declare arrays in Verilog, you can only access one element at a time. Almost all simulators supporting Verilog also support SystemVerilog.